# Add a class to the <body> tag on a node view

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

Is there any module that adds a field to all nodes and then add the value of that field as a class on the  tag of the page when the node is displayed?

Comment: are you asking about the content body `<div>` of the node or the `<body>` tag of the page?

Comment: the <body> tag of the page.

Comment: I am not aware of one out of the box, but it would be fairly simple and straightforward utilizing `hook_preprocess_html()` to look if a node was being presented, and if so, and that field was populated, to add its (sanitized) contents to the `$classes` variable.

Comment: ...or `$classes_array` variable rather (like what @sam152 details)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple and could likely be done in `template.php`. I would start with the following:

1. hook_preprocess_html() to hook into the rendering of the `<body>` tag.
2. menu_get_object() for loading the current node (in some themes it might already be present in `$variables` as  `$variables['node']`).
3. Grab the data the user entered into the field using `field_get_items` or something similar.
4. Pass it to `drupal_clean_css_identifier` to ensure it's ready to be used as a class.
5. Add it to the end of the `$variables['classes_array']` variable.
6. Clear the cache to ensure your new hook is picked up.

Comment: I knew this solution but I would like to use a module out of the box. Thank you.

Comment: This is being examined here: https://drupal.org/node/1852904 as part of the "field_formatter_class" module. Feel free to get involved with the development by testing, requesting or submitting a patch.